# ASP MVC Submit button not doing anything. At all

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a (simple) ASP MVC view:

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="dashboard-left" class="col-md-8">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("ConfigureOffers", "Offers", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                <p style="font-size: large;"><strong>Available</strong></p>
            </div> 
            <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
                <div class="widget" style="background:#fff !important">

                    @{
                        int i = 0;
                    }
                    @foreach (var prod in Model.allProducts)
                    {
                        <div class="accordion-group">
                            <div class="accordion-heading">
                                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="accordion2" href="#collapse@(i)">
                                    <h4 class="widgettitle" id="QuickTitle">> @prod.Description_VC</h4>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapse@(i)" class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px;">
                                <div class="accordion-inner" style="margin-left: 10px;">
                                    <div style="padding-bottom: 10px;"><strong>Total product:</strong> @{
                                        for (int k = 0; k < Model.OfferHeaders.Count(); k++)
                                        {
                                            if (Model.OfferHeaders[k].Product_ID == prod.Product_ID)
                                            {
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.OfferHeaders[k].Amount_DEC);
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    </div> @*prod div*@
                                </div> @*accordion-inner*@
                        @{i++;}
                            </div>
                        <div style="clear:both;"></div>                               
                     </div>
                    } 
                 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Save Changes" />   
                </div> @*widget*@
            </div> @*accordion*@
           }
    </div>
    <!-- col-md-4 -->
</div>
<!--row-->
```

The basis of this view was taken from another (working page), but for some reason, clicking the submit button doesn't trigger the server action detailed in the `BeginForm` element. I get no errors from Visual Studio, nor any JavaScript errors from the browser console, and nothing seems to happen server-side.

Comment: It is possible that it is blocked by client side validation, check your view model and see if there's any validation rules you defined been violated.

Comment: I have removed all client validation from the VM to try and sort out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- One possible reason for Action not happening is mainly when you put
  the action in the View and also created the page. but i think you
  have forgot mentioning the `ActionResult` in the controller.
- Another possible option is you have to use `[HttpPost]` above your
  method in controller where you specified the `ActionResult`

> ```
> [HttpPost]
> public ActionResult ConfigureOffers(ModelClass instance)
> {
>     ...
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Other possible reasons

- The routes are not correct
- The Form Action property is not correct
- You are using nested FORM tags